# Recode multiple numeric values into new values in R

Tags: r, numeric, recode, unique-values

I want to recode many unique numeric values (>3000) of one column into new values. 
The unique values appears many times in the column!
I am using R and all available functions like recode need the definition of all new values! Is there a way to define the new values as a range?

values: 131181420120103,  131181420120307, 4330108120070420, 5330068820110810 ...

possible new values:1, 2, 3, 4, ...

Comment: Maybe `as.integer(as.factor(x))`

Comment: I used it and then tried again "recode_to" function. It's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` on the column

```
data$col1 <- match(data$col1, unique(data$col1))
```